# Check if realm object is deleted

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Realm java has a function **isValid()** to check if a realm object is deleted/invalidated.

Is there a similar function to find it in realm swift?

I get 'Realm object has been deleted or invalidated' crash quite often, when updating those objects.

Comment: you should also check this topic for avoiding this kind of problems https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3195

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> An object can no longer be accessed if the object has been deleted from the containing `realm` or if `isInvalidated` is called on the containing `realm`.

this is [the Documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Object.html#/s:vC10RealmSwift6Object13isInvalidatedSb) of `Object.isInvalidated`.

add
`override var isInvalidated: Bool { return super.isInvalidated }` to your `Object`

Comment: it works. But the property is not isInvalidated. It is only 'invalidated'. Thanks.

Comment: Please correct the variable, so i can mark it as correct answer.

Comment: sorry @Shob-Z , Is my carelessness

Comment: @Shob-Z: Accorrding to [the Documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Object.html#/s:vC10RealmSwift6Object13isInvalidatedSb), the property is called `isInvalidated`. Or am i getting something wrong?

Comment: @r-dent maybe api has changed